# How come checking for printable bytes is faster with the "in" operator rather than interval comparisons?

Tags: python, time-complexity, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out how come the 'in' operator gives better performance than checking if a value is within some intervals bounds.

How come the first piece of code is slower than the second one? Intuitively I would expect the first piece of code to be faster (3 boolean operations + 4 integer comparisons), since it only checks the bounds of each interval for every byte, while the second code will iterate over the entire array of our charset (compare against every integer in an array of length=100).

```
import random

data = random.randbytes(1000000)
a_lower, a_upper, b_lower, b_upper = (9, 13, 32, 126)
%timeit [((x >= a_lower and x <= a_upper) or (x >= b_lower and x <= b_upper)) for x in data]
```

results in around 82 ms

```
import string
import random

data = random.randbytes(1000000)
charset = bytearray(string.printable, "ascii")
%timeit [x in charset for x in data]
```

results in around 44 ms

I have looked into CPython implementation of bytesarray "in", and [it looks like it eventually reaches memchr](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b8d808ddd77f84de9f93adcc2aede2879eb5241e/Objects/bytes_methods.c#L718)

The only theory I'm left with, is that the first piece of code might have more function calls within it, and that ends up taking more CPU time than the difference between the number of "basic operations".

Comment: Python is a dynamic, interpreted language. Every basic Python operation translates to a lot of machine operations.

Comment: What times do you get for just `x >= a_lower` and for just `x in charset` after setting let's say `x = 30`?

Comment: because `x in charset` will be very fast, and all done in the C layer. the size fo `charset` is small, only 100.

Comment: OTOH, `((x >= a_lower and x <= a_upper) or (x >= b_lower and x <= b_upper))` while fast enough, is doing quite a lot in the python bytecode level. over 16 bytecode instructions

Answer (score -1):

I put both functions into the `dis` module to observe the number of operations.

```py
import string
import random
import dis

def function_01():
    ''' the first function '''
    data = random.randbytes(1000000)
    a_lower, a_upper, b_lower, b_upper = (9, 13, 32, 126)    
    
    return [((x >= a_lower and x <= a_upper) or (x >= b_lower and x <= b_upper)) for x in data]


def function_02():
    ''' the second function '''
    data = random.randbytes(1000000)
    charset = bytearray(string.printable, "ascii")    
    
    return [x in charset for x in data]


# Disassemble the function and capture the results
disassembled_01 = dis.Bytecode(function_01)
disassembled_02 = dis.Bytecode(function_02)

# convert to list and count number of operations
operation_count_01 = len(list(disassembled_01))
operation_count_02 = len(list(disassembled_02))

print(f"The function 01 has {operation_count_01} operations.")
print(f"The function 02 has {operation_count_02} operations.")
```

which returns this:

```
The function 01 has 52 operations.
The function 02 has 34 operations.
```

From this, it can be seen that function_02 is considerable shorter than function_01. Whilst this does not show exact time itself (there are other factors), it certainly gives a good idea of function with the most operations which is a key factor to time.

Comment: that doesn't by itself explain this (I didn't downvote, btw)

Comment: No, that is precisely what I'm pointing out, the number of OP codes **will not be proportionate to the time**. In this particular case, it happens that the implementation of `in` (which will eventually correspond to the execution of a `CONTAINS_OP`) for `bytes` is faster in this particular case. That won't always be the case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i would be interested to see if you can show an example where this is not the case. . . especially when the number of operations is meaningfully larger !!

Comment: It is *trivial*. Simply define a type with a `__contains__` that does `time.sleep(3600)` or whatever arbitrarily long time you want.

Comment: if both functions perform the same `time.sleep(3600)` and one function performs it twice or many more times than the other.  I assert that the function performing more similar operations will take longer.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your hypothetical is supposed to demonstrate. Let me try to explain it another way,  `dis.dis("x in y")` produces the *same* bytecode. But *the actual objects involved matter*. You can't tell that from the byte code. If `y` is some object that implements `__contains__` that just has a while loop that never completes, versus another that simply returns `True` unconditionally, you wouldn't be able to tell *from this bytecode*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is a good point. i agree that using `dis` for all of those such cases would be sub optimal. It has its use cases where it is helpful for understanding.